# MariaDB Galera Cluster: issue with replication

Tags: wordpress, mariadb, galera

Here is my setup:

1. 4 VMs (running on CentOS 7)

   - VM1 with mariadb-client and maxscale for load balancing (I have tried haproxy, results are the same). httpd and php (I am testing this with WordPress installation)
   - VM2, VM3, VM4 with mariadb-server, galera, rsync
2. Software installation

   - adding repository "curl -sS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash" on all 4 VMs
   - installing MariaDB-server on VM2, VM3, VM4 (this includes galera and all the required software)
   - installing maxscale and MariaDB-client on VM1
3. Editing config files

   - on VM2, VM3, VM4 I have added:
     https://gist.github.com/yarko686/5adb7b24784c4c3c24a526519623d930 
     to /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf
   - on VM1 I have added the following lines to /etc/maxscale.cnf https://gist.github.com/a67e94afaa4ecc57ccb985d897ee3e87.git
4. Staring the cluster

   - on VM2 I have executed galera_new_cluster
   - on VM3 and VM4 I have executed systemctl start mariadb
5. Checking the cluster

   - on VM2 I am accessing mysql using mysql -u root then executing:
     show global status like 'wsrep_cluster_size';
   - I receive this output https://gist.github.com/yarko686/a63c925b3275d239f38d50f0651e45ef it means that there are 3 machines in cluster
6. Creating maxscale user and wordpress users

   - Login to MySQL CLI on VM2 using mysql -u root and executing the following commands
     https://gist.github.com/yarko686/950ea62f79638a6f293c28b99dd19f7b
   - for WordPress user I use the same commands, except *.*. I these cases, I'm using wordpress_db.* instead.
7. The main issue.

   - after importing WordPress database, it is properly created only on VM2 only. On VM3 and VM4 the database and tables are created, however, for some reason they are empty.
   - If I access wordpress database through MySQL CLI using my wordpress user and create new table with some data it gets replicated, but when I add user to my wp_users table (or add user through wp-admin) it is not replicated. The record gets created only on VM2 and not on VM3 and VM4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see if the tables are innodb instead of isam.
I know on my setup when I imported old isam tables, the tables would appear, but the data wouldn't replicate. I had to convert all of the tables to innodb.